# how to inject a folder or file into ISO file to appear on desktop?

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have windows server 2008 32 bit with SP1 pack ISO and sp2 pack exe. Now I want to inject this exe file into ISO file to appear on desktop after fresh installation of OS. How is it possible and where do I need to put this exe file in ISO contents. I know about ISO editors but do not know where to put this exe file or a folder to appear on desktop after OS installation any quick help appreciated..thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Server 2008, but with Server 2008 R2 at least you can use [RT Server Customizer](http://2kr2.rt7lite.com/rt-server-customizer.html) to easily do the following:

- Integration of [service packs](http://www.rtwincustomize.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1465:how-to-slipstream-windows-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1-using-rt-server-customizer&catid=69:unattended-tools&Itemid=433) (*slipstreaming*), security updates, hotfixes, drivers, language packs, 3rd party applications.
- Components removal
- Tweaks
- Unattended installation
- Customization
- Creation of bootable ISO or DVD

[image: 1]